# Class action settlement reached for former stock holders. Is it worth the hassle to participate?

Tags: stocks, trading, lawsuit-settlement

I received a letter that [class action settlement has been reached](http://www.chelseatherapeuticssettlement.com/) for former CHTP stock holders. If I understand correctly I would have to file a claim and I could possibly get some money back if I bought CHTP stock from September 20, 2010 through May 21, 2012 and incurred loss.

**Has anyone had experience with similar cases (i.e. roughly how much money is it possible to get back from such class action lawsuits)?  What are the risks (e.g. did you have to pay any legal fees before even being able to get any money back)? Any other things that would be good to know and if it is even worth one'stime?**

If I  understand correctly then in particular case the court has already awarded $5,500,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadline for submitting a claim was September 4th, 2016 - therefore you are no longer eligible. 
That being said, you probably did not miss much. [According to the settlement notice](http://www.chelseatherapeuticssettlement.com/Portals/0/Documents/Chelsea%20Therapeutics%20Settlement%20Notice.pdf) you can expect to be paid about 14 cents per share, on claims exceeding $10 (below $10 you don't get paid).

Read the settlement notice for more info.

Comment: It is interesting that I received the notice only on September 3rd or even 4th when it was already deadline to file claim.